# reference count

Tags: c++

In my current project, lots of legacy code was designed to use reference count. I know the very basic idea behind it. But I would like to enhance my knowledge for this area since I have to start to use reference count in my daily coding task.

Is there a good book or resource that show me how to use or how to design a good framework/classes that adopt reference count.

Thank you

Comment: The biggest and most prevalent system I can think of that uses reference counting as its resource management strategy is COM, part of Windows. Might want to try looking around for resources about that (although, COM is a lot more than just ref-counting ;)

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but wiki(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is a good resource.

Comment: I definitely agree with @Mike.  COM reference counting is very well thought out and it's relatively easy to find implementations that cover issues such as thread safety in reference counting and how to deal with cycles.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, really.

In your structure you have an integer.  When the object is allocated it starts out as 1.

If you're passed one of these objects and you wish to retain it for longer than the lifetime of your function, you bump the reference count by 1.  This is known as "holding a reference", and prevents the object from being freed.  An example of this would be if you insert it into a collection, or are going to make use of it later, or in another thread. [Nota bene: If you use it in multiple threads you need to make sure the increment/decrement of the count are done with atomic ops.]

If you were responsible for increasing the reference count (or if you were the one who allocated the object in the first place), you decrement the reference count when you don't need the pointer anymore and don't care if it gets freed.

If the reference count reaches zero, you de-allocate.

There are some drawbacks to reference counting:

- You can't have data structures with cycles in them.  If A has a reference to B and B has a reference to A, A and B's refcount will never go to zero.  There are some strategies to avoid this while still having circular structures but they are quite complicated.
- In a multi-threaded program, incrementing and decrementing requires atomic Read-Modify-Write instructions, which can be slow.  This is especially bad since programs using reference counting will typically change the reference count very frequently, and with atomic ops across multiple threads that's a problem.
- It's hard to debug when something goes wrong.  You could see a memory leak, double-free or use-after-free, but it won't be clear immediately at the point of the crash who inappropriately modified the refcount.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about smart pointers in boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Shared pointer there uses reference counting:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you probably have seen is *intrusive reference-counting* where the class has to be specifically designed so its objects can be reference-counted. You don't need any special precautions if you go for *non-intrusive reference-counting* instead, as employed by `boost::shared_ptr<T>`.

You can read the [documentation at Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or section 20.9.10.2 of the [current C++0x standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf).

Comment: Note that with the use of the C++0x std::make_shared, shared_ptr can become as efficient as intrusive reference counting.  Though admittedly that's a QOI issue (the implementation doesn't have to go to the effort).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, look at the section in the `boost::shared_ptr` manual about custom deleters and managing COM objects.  You can have the reference counts automatically decremented when the last `shared_ptr` reference disappears, preventing many bugs.  You can also use `boost::intrusive_ptr`, which is designed for objects with their own reference count management.